# XSD Validation Failed: Element has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

When i validate the XSD file it gives the following error

**"src-element.3: Element 'Account' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element."**

```
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Account" type="account:Account">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ID">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="NAME"/>
                                    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="PHONE"/>
                                    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="CATEGORY"/>
                                    <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="LASTMODIFIED"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Please help to resolve and make it a valid xsd.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the answer. You have two choices:

- Remove the "type"-Attribute from your element with name="Account"
- Remove the "complexType"-Node in your element with name="Account"

It's only allowed to do one of them, either you name a type or you anonymously define it inside.

Comment: I cannot remove the type attribute so i removed complexType node but i get the error as at the sequence node as   "s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of Account' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at:  sequence.

Comment: If you want to define the inner structure of this type you got inside of the Account you need the "complexType"-Node with its inside, what's the problem with deleting the attribute?

The "type"-Attribute is only an alternative, if the type you want to have in there is simple (like "xs:string"). I think you need to remove the attribute.